# PayPal REST API sandbox testing giving UNKNOWN ERROR

Tags: rest, paypal

I have been trying to test the REST API for PayPal for direct credit card transactions and I always get an error saying "UNKNOWN_ERROR".

I have included all relevant Auth Headers etc and I am getting proper responses in case of any Validation Errors, but only when I try to test with a positive scenario I get this error. I have tried with all possible credit card numbers (Numbers from my Sandbox test accounts as well as other Mod 10 compliant CC numbers), but nothing works. Has this got something to do with my PayPal account itself? It should not because Direct CC payments are supposed to be enabled at least for Sandbox across all countries.

This is for a Salesforce integration to PayPal but currently I don't even care about that, I'm trying get a positive response from SOAPUI.

These is one of the Transactions from my Dev account Dashboard:

Metadata:

> {
>       "url": "/v1/payments/payment",
>       "create_time": "2015-10-31T08:03:41Z",
>       "additional_properties": {},
>       "account_number": "1300707500520479771",
>       "client_id": "AfWXek5HKSxF-IryNlxeCR8LLbCC_VYp8d3BlzJBaE-SNF3gfKPb-lEarpOu7EvBVFW-WzuWrsotojee",
>       "id": "563475df36b75d6a5faf5251"
>   }

Request:

> {
>       "body": {
>           "intent": "sale",
>           "payer": {
>               "payment_method": "credit_card",
>               "funding_instruments": [
>                   {
>                       "credit_card": {
>                           "first_name": "Betsy",
>                           "last_name": "Buyer",
>                           "expire_month": 11,
>                           "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx3109",
>                           "cvv2": "***",
>                           "expire_year": 2020,
>                           "type": "visa"
>                       }
>                   }
>               ]
>           },
>           "transactions": [
>               {
>                   "amount": {
>                       "currency": "USD",
>                       "total": "27.78"
>                   },
>                   "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
>               }
>           ]
>       },
>       "header": {
>           "x-pp-ads-performed": "false",
>           "content-length": "653",
>           "x-forwarded-server": "jensenhealey.ca1.paypal.com",
>           "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate",
>           "x-forwarded-host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
>           "user-agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)",
>           "x-forwarded-for": "10.72.108.11",
>           "x-pp-silover": "name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D3715445846",
>           "connection": "Keep-Alive",
>           "accept": "*/*",
>           "client-auth": "No cert",
>           "host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
>           "authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxK48O",
>           "x-pp-corrid": "f6b72bc35cbb5",
>           "pp_remote_addr": "182.66.112.160",
>           "content-type": "application/json",
>           "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp": "platformapiserv"
>       },
>       "additional_properties": {},
>       "method": "POST"
>   }

Response:

> {
>       "status": 400,
>       "duration_time": 1054,
>       "body": {
>           "message": "An unknown error has occurred",
>           "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR",
>           "name": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
>           "debug_id": "f6b72bc35cbb5"
>       },
>       "additional_properties": {},
>       "header": {
>           "Content-Length": "185",
>           "Content-Language": "*",
>           "CORRELATION-ID": "f6b72bc35cbb5",
>           "Date": "Sat, 31 Oct 2015 08:03:41 GMT",
>           "Connection": "close",
>           "Paypal-Debug-Id": "f6b72bc35cbb5",
>           "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host\u003dslcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId\u003d380",
>           "Content-Type": "application/json"
>       }
>   }

Comment: PayPal has some issues at last Friday and last weekend, could you try the request again ? can you still get this issue today ?

Comment: @ZhaoSamanta Still the same output. Where can I raise a Support case for Developer issues?